# How to use Request.Form to retrieve value when using masterpages

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

I have setup a hiddenfield control and a linkbutton on an aspx Masterpages content page.

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" value='<%# Eval("ID") %>'/>
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" postbackurl="orderhistorydetail.aspx">View</asp:LinkButton>
```

When trying to retrieve the value on the postback page using this code...

```
string oid = Request.Form[HiddenField1];
```

I am getting the error...

> The name 'HiddenField1' does not exist in the current context.

Is this because of materpages? How can I fix this?

EDITED...

I viewed the source html that was generated for the page that has the hiddenfield control on it and this was the output...

```
<input type="hidden" name="ctl00$MainContentPlaceHolder1$ListView1$ctrl0$ctl00$HiddenField1" id="MainContentPlaceHolder1_ListView1_ctrl0_HiddenField1_0" value="12386026" />
```

Now, as for the code you originally gave me, I updated it to this...

```
HiddenField hf = Page.PreviousPage.Master.FindControl("MainContentPlaceHolder1").FindControl("ListView1").FindControl("HiddenField1") as HiddenField;
```

Still no luck. Am I getting close?

Answer (score 0):

The page you are posting to has no knowledge of the Controls that are present on the previous page. You need to use FindControl for that.

```
HiddenField hf = Page.PreviousPage.Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1").FindControl("HiddenField1") as HiddenField;
string oid = hf.Value;
```

Or if you really want to use Request.Form you need to use the UniqueID.

```
string oid = Request.Form[HiddenField1.UniqueID];
```

First you must find the PlaceHolder of the Page that is using a Master Page and then the correct Control within the PlaceHolder.

If you want to check what all the Posted values are, use this:

```
foreach (string s in Request.Form.Keys)
{
    Response.Write(s.ToString() + ": " + Request.Form[s] + "<br>");
}
```

Comment: Ok, so how would I then retrieve the value of just that hiddenfield1 that would normally be retrieved using... string oid = Request.Form[HiddenField1]; ?

Comment: I am getting this error though on the first line of code you have presented.. Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: First, make sure that `ContentPlaceHolder1` matches the ID you gave to the `asp:Content` in the page using the Master. If `HiddenField1` is inside another Control you need to find that first by navigating the Control Tree by adding another `FindControl` before `.FindControl("HiddenField1")`

Comment: Ah, in a ListVIew... You do realize you need to access those controls by the Item Index of the ListView. And since you don't know which item in the ListView did the form post the above code will not work. Then your best bet is to extract the correct `Request.Form` by looping them and get the correct post.

Comment: Not really, because the controls are in a ListView. As a last resort you can always use `Request.Form["ctl00$MainContentPlaceHolder1$ListView1$ctrl0$ctl00$HiddenField1"]`

Comment: I appreciate your help. Would you be able to give me an example of how to loop them to get the correct post?

Comment: I already did. Loop all items in `foreach (string s in Request.Form.Keys)`, check if the key contains `ListView1` and get the value you need.

Comment: I am sorry, how do I check the key if it contains ListView1. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Like this `if (s.Contains("myValue")...`

Comment: It seems as though masterpages is affecting this as well.